# How to set default program to open a file in helm?

Tags: helm

In `helm`, when finding a file, `C-c C-x` would prompt for open with external program option. Is there a way to set a default program, say, `smplayer` for `.mov` file. Then I can just press `Enter` to open it.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer by pressing <kbd>C-u C-c C-x</kbd> when running <kbd>C-x C-f</kbd>, which was rebind to `helm-find-files`.

```
(setq helm-external-programs-associations (quote (("rmvb" . "smplayer") ("mp4" . "smplayer"))))
```

This set helm to open files using designated programs. In this case, open .rmvb and .mp4 file using smplayer.

and

```
(setq large-file-warning-threshold 500000000)
```

Set the warning threshold to 500 MB, which will get ride of `File abc.mp4 is large (330.2M), really open? (y or n) y` annoying message. (Courtesy of @Nsukami _)

I hope this might be helpful to other new helm user.

Comment: If you open the file with external program the first time, Helm will ask. After that, Helm remembers your selection until you decide to choose something else.

Comment: @TuDo Yes. I noticed that `helm` wrote the above line (I modified a little) to my `.emacs` file. Helm and projectile really changed the habit of using emacs. Amazing package! Thank you.